# "What should I do next?" instructions in email (regarding question closure) are irrelevant to the OP when OP was one of those who cast the close vote

Tags: bug, closed-questions, email

On Apr 20, 2022, 3:40 AM Indian Standard Time, I received this email from Stack Exchange (do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email):

[image]

[image]

> ### **This question is off-topic.** It is
>
> #### closed and not accepting answers.
>
> **Question**: [Why are contact pages not consistent?](https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/ls/click?upn=FhKQFemTFIJzn5ywFPMHvooREUT7vDvcYvuMpf3lFkkbKhUevZEJc8cKm-2BCvsN2ZrgaARGl-2FXdZ33dTv4S6Zmy6tXy5B5KHwxvJZ-2FjTjED-2F6y-2F6t3HKu2XJxd6JgSp17Vuf5_SYvJYU-2FCncYmodtGRD5UVhXuGlChAW7aXPD4VNrt-2Bd0xBb04S-2FemY-2Fp0A2fbyEDMpA2pvB-2FS0eL-2BFn3ogyiGZoPZIpe4o9NFWjbkenmdHjEbVeqPJXokj3dPlncpv0wY5Tr9pqvHK-2FQrlElCdeAj7rsJ6GSdAtNDLdve2NgZwi5Wn4TprxfTdrSYVLZH5scPO4t5NvR5ACAlsWtwL36-2Faf8l1L9IO2vDJ54auqhJvHoNQB8heuSWbnLkXjR-2FYzBpHeqUR0Pwakufif4IP5sC0seivt-2FpdX85EeBs2irrfYH9hnTURjWeadNZmiunXUbAWFXPg1qcbSLwxXzSOxRsxvlcu7UMiCqIVgvnCZELi0QqwJ75oP9IY7HLUsK-2BPuhQRLgW8C5neZaXSR5TnTyQXgkoW-2Fw7cBb1PJvxOCoBsLwyx0fFzQT8dwOeqgkKXeOPdTs3YX9kr49j1bbYxduKgUmdxiifBXKj8io32-2BcadWXUviv8sbMaYwxv7-2F0mK5GG1Xgn-2FamXyFGQrLGYWb-2F2ffDuD-2BAaQDlxDICJitYljgGvxfoI6p-2F855kCNJVy-2FVY3)
> **Feedback**:
>
> **What should I do next?**
>
> - **Read the [comments](https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/ls/click?upn=FhKQFemTFIJzn5ywFPMHvooREUT7vDvcYvuMpf3lFkkbKhUevZEJc8cKm-2BCvsN2ZrgaARGl-2FXdZ33dTv4S6Zmy6tXy5B5KHwxvJZ-2FjTjED-2By07KxJ2YEp9QgJCix5OLp-2F9lAUj4gNLlyRweb0rpRIw-3D-3Dj0VX_SYvJYU-2FCncYmodtGRD5UVhXuGlChAW7aXPD4VNrt-2Bd0xBb04S-2FemY-2Fp0A2fbyEDMpA2pvB-2FS0eL-2BFn3ogyiGZoPZIpe4o9NFWjbkenmdHjEbVeqPJXokj3dPlncpv0wY5Tr9pqvHK-2FQrlElCdeAj7rsJ6GSdAtNDLdve2NgZwi5Wn4TprxfTdrSYVLZH5scPO4t5NvR5ACAlsWtwL36-2Faf8l1L9IO2vDJ54auqhJvHoNQB8heuSWbnLkXjR-2FYzBpHeqUR0Pwakufif4IP5sC0seivt-2FpdX85EeBs2irrfYH9hnTURjWeadNZmiunXUbA-2BK-2BvDyIRXusbg1k9Qtkg3QnwfVs3vsHxKwQXGYtyuwuRRXGg61zqfRI6IV0XRzegcf5SjwmuJmQhq27AHW4VtvFHT3FHPVln3ANOdQqYtx4atI-2FkevQg2CBjaHbdGvYZOOVoL9kWaoRnRoWLOPBMULjG1zzzFJPkVKCDh9F-2FDYUtHOszCzPPMCXKwWSGne3famRRm7-2FTRyZM8OJ1WgmkbKWqCdNNXJCm2EmrNV4bkQLztmrZ-2FQwduDxxwhu0zPOE).** The community provided specific feedback about why your question is off-topic for Ask Ubuntu Meta.
> - **Review on-topic guidelines for Ask Ubuntu Meta.** Determine if your question is [on-topic](https://sg-links.stackoverflow.email/ls/click?upn=FhKQFemTFIJzn5ywFPMHvooREUT7vDvcYvuMpf3lFkmNIaa585njDKWuvtxOo2lsI4alfpKBYSFTndS-2FhpVoUw-3D-3DAtT-_SYvJYU-2FCncYmodtGRD5UVhXuGlChAW7aXPD4VNrt-2Bd0xBb04S-2FemY-2Fp0A2fbyEDMpA2pvB-2FS0eL-2BFn3ogyiGZoPZIpe4o9NFWjbkenmdHjEbVeqPJXokj3dPlncpv0wY5Tr9pqvHK-2FQrlElCdeAj7rsJ6GSdAtNDLdve2NgZwi5Wn4TprxfTdrSYVLZH5scPO4t5NvR5ACAlsWtwL36-2Faf8l1L9IO2vDJ54auqhJvHoNQB8heuSWbnLkXjR-2FYzBpHeqUR0Pwakufif4IP5sC0seivt-2FpdX85EeBs2irrfYH9hnTURjWeadNZmiunXUbA2z9B2S7WqzJLbaTjXhwHjMNXqiTTYHK0TVO0HyefI8Z9SrbJt-2FPYgNhqVgWqCGI9cGLMMV9iYZqIAsz-2F8ZT1siYkkG2Z0rSNlRK4RiAWl4uP2gvterN3FwIdxYCWZZE3xjbA5kns-2BiWiLpyShR8cjUOIau5sRo5FGvhMeXO6BAkCftdb-2BNWA-2BwcTBPW1mlfc-2FfK8rpggj4CO0Pa-2BgB1EyVbZLcGsG5U5xx8Ck-2FXBRvi4qP9CHAmBf7C4U5grBVG5) for this community.
> - **If your question is on-topic, edit it.** After it has been sufficiently edited, the question will become visible to the public.
> - **Submit your edits.** Edits will be reviewed by trusted community members. If approved, the question will become visible to the public.
>
> Thanks for your contributions. We’re glad you’re here.
>
> <sub>You're receiving this message because your Ask Ubuntu Meta activity triggered this tip or reminder.</sub>

Link of the closed question: https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/19700 (The question has been closed and deleted, so normal users might not able to see the post.)

Screenshot of timeline of the post:

[image]

I do not think that this kind of email is appropriate when the OP cast a close vote on their own question. I request the staff to fix the issue.

---

The "*What should I do next?*" instructions are irrelevant to the OP as the OP was one of those who cast the close vote.

Comment: So you probably hadn't read your inbox notification saying that it was closed, and your email settings then made the site send you this, because you asked for emails...

Comment: Well - then again, if he closed his own question, and he didn't lead a mysterious double like like Tyler Durden... he would be aware he closed it, which would be the core of the issue.

Comment: @Luuklag I have changed my question a bit